# Is there a XSD Schema of Activity Stream feed?

Tags: xsd, schema

I am trying to map Activity Stream feed to Java entity beans using JAXB. If there were a XSD schema of ActivityStream, it would be so much easier.

Does anyone know if there exists a XSD schema of ActivityStrea.ms?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully I have some G&T to wipe away the vomit in my mouth from this being the only link on the entire web that has what you and I are looking for:

https://code.google.com/p/nter/source/browse/feeds/activity-streams-1.0.xsd?repo=xml-schemas-devel&r=741fa55f12e5f4b4e5ccab5b84fbb6abcf256427

Three years latter and this is where "social" stands. Machines need specs too, not just humans. This is the only satisfactory "we can" in activitystrea.ms world.

For more soapboxing, visit yoyodyne.net!